# how to show the response next to the regarding td

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

when i clicking the forth button it reaponse is showing on the first td i want to show the response next to the regarding td below is my code can one help me . thanks

(i.e here i geting the `$status` using query but i want this status to display in last td when the button is clicked )

**HTML**

```
echo '<td  class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["clientid"].'</td>
    <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientid" class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>   
    <td id="CPH_GridView1_country" class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
    <td class="edit3 '.$rows["net_id"].' "> <input type="button" class="edit2" value="R" /> </td>
    <td id="responsecontainer"></td>'
```

**ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".edit2").click(function() {       

        arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split( " " );

         var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;         

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "clientnetworkpricelist/display.php",    
        data: "clientid="+ clientid+"&rowid="+arr[1],       

        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
});

</script>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$client_id=$_POST['clientid'];

$feild=$_POST['field'];
        $data= $_POST['value'];
        $rownum=$_POST['rowid'];  

       $sql_selectsupplier="select status from $client_id WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";
$querysupplier = mysql_query($sql_selectsupplier);


$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($querysupplier))
{

    $status=$row['status'];

}

 print $sql_selectsupplier;

  print $status       


?>
```

imAGE

[image]

Comment: What exactly your $status print here ? in the php file 
What error you got in your console?

Comment: $status was equal,increase and decrease

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried alerting the response in the script file or printing it on console if the response is also correct in the script file and you have no error in the console please try this once

```
document.getElementById('responsecontainer').innerHTML=response;
```

in place of

```
$("#responsecontainer").html(response);
```

If you didnt get the td fill after this also sure there is a error in the console please post it

Comment: thanks it showing the response but it not showing the response next to the button clicked

Comment: I UPLOADED the image how its now when i clicking the forth button it reaponse is showing on the first td i want to show the response next to the regarding td

Comment: I think your html with 4 td is in the loop and then each of the fourth td will have the same id because its static "responsecontainer" what you can do is make it dynamic with the loop index like "responsecontainer_1" and so on and and you can give the same id to the button like "button_1" also so when the button is clicked then take the unique id _1 or _2 then in the javascript code change the innerhtml of the td with the id you got for the button click hope you got the idea what i am saying Accept and upvote my answer if i helped you

Comment: thank you for your comment can you please help me with the code to how to do this

Comment: The image shows that there are multiple rows please post your code to generate them i wanna see the looping and then i will edit your code only